# How to define ssh host key on EC2 to avoid failed verification when connecting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

We have a bastion host and we want to practice immutable infrastructure. That means, when we update the host machine we simply replace it instead of running updates on it. Now, replacing a EC2 machine [will create a new host key](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/host-key) when the new machine boots up, causing a new fingerprint that is not known to clients in their `known_hosts` file and ultimately lead to the `Host key verification failed` error.

How can I define the host key without exposing it in some script or terraform code?

There are multiple questions regarding `Host key verification failed`, so please note: this is not about `authorized_keys`, nor is it about changing IP addresses and default AWS DNS hostnames when rebooting an EC2 instance as covered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30432105/1242922. A custom DNS entry points to our bastion machine, so this is not part of the problem as far as I can tell.

Comment: [linux - How can I avoid SSH's host verification for known hosts? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/125324/how-can-i-avoid-sshs-host-verification-for-known-hosts)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I guess your advice is to disable the check. At least I could not find a different answer in your linked question. Not really what I had in mind, but I see that it avoids the problem.