# Host verification Failed Jenkins AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have setup a gitlab repo and wrote a script for auto deployment inside the git repo using aws-ec2.

here is the script

```
while getopts b: flag
do
    case "${flag}" in
        b) branch=${OPTARG};;
       
    esac
done



ssh xxx@ec2xx.xxx.xxx.xxxx.com "cd ~/code/foldername && git fetch --all && git checkout ${branch} && git pull && sudo sh scripts/run-in-docker.sh  "^C
```

here is the output i am getting:

```
branch: ranch
Host key verification failed.
```

Any idea what I am missing now? a help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105552/host-key-verification-failed-amazon-ec2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Host key verification failed - amazon EC2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29105552/host-key-verification-failed-amazon-ec2)